# Overfitting and the number of observations

Tags: sample-size, overfitting

My professor stated in a side sentence that one possible way to approach the problem of overfitting is increasing the number of observations that we are using for training.

Even though, this makes kind of sense to me, it is very hard for me to phrase why this is the case.

I think, if we have more observations, it is harder to pick up idiosyncracies. Why? Because the impact on the loss function of adjusting the parameters to fit a single idiosyncracy gets smaller. If we increase observations, picking up one idiosyncracy will improve the loss function with respect to this observation however, the fraction of observations for which it is unbeneficial to adjust the parameters with respect to the idiosyncracy gets larger.

Is this somehow correct?

Comment: You could try yourself to do some simulations ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen as my professor stated this, I am not challenging the statement... I want to understand theoretically why this is the case.